# is it possible to make 2 condition that you write string stament and int stagement and make an operation with them in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want the program that if user doesn't write any value in bookno jtexfield which is named issbook_text in my program,it would give a error message like 'no way'
I wrote those codes but normally I expected it to work like I wish but it doesn't .what is my mistake ,I could not find it for days.

```
    public class lib {
    public lib()
    {
        gui();

    }
     int kitapno[]=new int[10]; 
     int kitapnoindex;
     int quantity[]=new int[10];
     int quantityindex;
     int kitapadetleri;


public void gui()
    {   
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {String issbookno_string=issbookno_text.getText();
    int issbookno_int=Integer.parseInt(issbookno_string);

    Date pt_issbook=new Date();
    DateFormat ptformat_issbook=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");                                             
   if(issbookno_string.equals(""))//if user don't fill out the issbook 
      name
   {  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(issbook_window,"no way");//print no 
        way to display
    }
   else 

   for(int i=0;i<kitapno.length;i++)
 {  if(issbookno_int==kitapno[i])
  {   row_issue[0]=kitapno[i];  

   row_issue[1]=issstudentid_text.getText();

   row_issue[2]=issstudentname_text.getText();

   row_issue[3]=issstudentcontact_text.getText();

   row_issue[4]=ptformat_issbook.format(pt_issbook);

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(issbook_window,"You have been succesfully issued a book");

   model_issue.addRow(row_issue);
    }


                                            }
                                        }               });[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: I'm getting trouble that I wrote those codes.Normally,when I don't write anything to book nojtexfield,it must give a no way error message but it doesn't look.

Comment: Could you update your question to make it more readable ? It is pretty hard to understand and I don't know how I can help you.

Comment: it probably is, but since I don't understand what exactly you're asking, I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I updated my question and  make it more clear and put the details.,In a nutshell, I appoint ed jtexfield .getText()   to issbookno_int  as a  string value which converted to string  but I can  not make an operation with them such as if it is null

Comment: As a complete aside I recommend you don’t use `DateFormat ` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: ohh well,thanks for the recommendation,I wasn't contented for my date codes.I updated it the way you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(issbookno_string.equals(""))//if user don't fill out the issbook 
      name
   {  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(issbook_window,"no way");//print no 
        way to display
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is because of the formatting or not, but `//` is used for single line comments, which means the "name" in the "if user don't fill out the issbook name" comment and "way to display" in the "print no way to display" aren't actually being commented, as they are on separate lines from the double slash. In order to add multi line comments, you could enclose the comments with `/*` instead.

Comment: Line comments wasn't a problem.it looks like wrong written comments in codes because of my inexperinence in stackoverflow.I put the codes a little untidy.I solved the problem that ı want to do ,thank you for your answer

Comment: Ah I see, my bad. Congrats on solving your issue though!